# Opinion on GUI for a Battleship game in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am making a battleship game for a project. While I have completed the logic and the game works with text input. I was hoping make a (very basic) GUI while still use the methods created for the text.

The two options I've been looking at are PyGame and Tkinter. PyGame does not seem to have a text output/label function. Tkinter does, but it doesn't seem as easy (i feel) as PyGame is.

Though I would love to give either of these frameworks the time they deserve, I have just over 60hrs before this is due.

I wanted to know if anyone one has any experience or insights and if it is a realistic option.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly trivial thing to do in Tkinter. A battleship game shows an array of coordinates which you can display as a grid of checkbuttons.

Comment: Tkinter is looking like my option for now. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could check [Kivy](http://kivy.org/), it's working in top of OpenGL, provide severals basics widgets (label, button, slider, textinput, layouts, ...), and you can create your own / display graphics etc. Works as a python framework, almost all platforms.

You can also check the recent [game contest](http://kivy.org/#contest) to see what you can do with it :)

Comment: Installing an additional package when this can be trivially implemented in Tkinter seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Cocos2D?
It's higher level, and it supports rich labeling (Class cocos.text.RichLabel)

http://cocos2d.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [pyqt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt)/[pyside](http://www.pyside.org) for this task. This lets you access the powerful Qt framework which has great documentation. If you design a game that does not need fast graphics you can simply use [QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) and related classes to display icons/numbers/whatever. Of course you can use [OpenGL](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/316) with Python and Qt as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can render text on pygame, just use:

### class pygame.font.Font

```
#create a new Font object from a file
pygame.font.Font(filename, size): return Font
pygame.font.Font(object, size): return Font
```

### method Font.render

```
#method of Font() to draw text on a new Surface
Font.render(text, antialias, color, background=None): return Surface
```

Simple example how to use text on pygame:

```
from pygame import font as pgfont, sprite as pgspr
import pygame as pg

    class FontSprite(pgspr.DirtySprite):
        def __init__(self, text, x, y):
            '''self.image = surface'''
            pgspr.DirtySprite.__init__(self)
            self.text = text
            self.color = [0,0,0]
            self.image = self.get_image()
            self.rect = pg.Rect((x, y), self.image.get_size())

        def get_image(self):
            self.dirty = 1
            return pgfont.Font('fonts\\BRLNSR.TTF', self.size).render(self.text,
                                                                      True,
                                                                      self.color)
```