# best look and feel gui for python

Tags: python, user-interface

This sounds stupid and there are a lot of thread related to this topic but yet I am asking.

Is there some good ui library that has catchy graphical interface? many suggest for pythons default ui tkinter some suggest wxPython. They seems some like windows look. Adobe air has cool look in ui. Also GNOME 3.x has nice look when we press Super key for search. Is there any GUI library that can provide me these kind of effects in ui?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.co9m), it's a very powerful, well documented and portable GUI. There are two Python bindings out there, one is called [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), the other [PySide](http://www.pyside.org). Qt runs on Windows, Linux and MacOS. Additionally, this question has been asked a lot (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346022/589206) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346022/589206)). Some simple examples can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/PyQt4).

Comment: I am currently using QT designer in fedora 16. I like the view of Oxygen style (Form -> preview in -> Oxygen style). I am just starting this, so I have very little knowledge in designing in QT. Can you tell how can I change default theme into Oxygen style?

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyle.html#details contains an explanation, you can even create your own style if you like.  http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#QApplication is another starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 has [`tkinter.ttk`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html), which has the Tkinter API but adapts to the platform's UI style and theme.